# main folders in file manager unlinked after reinstall

Tags: debian, cinnamon, file-manager, nemo

I recently upgraded to Debian 11 Bullseye. From the previous Debian Buster I had rsync'ed the whole user folder onto an external hard drive. The internal drive was completely formatted and after the install was finished, the user folder from the external drive was brought back with rsync. Specifically the command was

```
rsync -aXv
```

..so chosen as I had changed the user name and hoped that the files with permissions and group from the old username from the external drive would copy with the new username in permissions and groups which they thankfully did.

In the Cinammon file manager however, most of the folders, except desktop were not linked to the buttons:

[image: unlinked folders in file manager]

You can still find and click in the main folders (Documents, Videos etc) in the panel on the right, but it is part of the usability that clicking on those icons on the left open up those folders.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Forgot to mention there had been a change of username with the new install. Also realised that the Cinnamon file manager is called 'Nemo'

There is a file in the user directory:

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

which looks like this and is part of the configuration of Nemo:

```
file:///home/username/Dokumente
file:///home/username/Musik
file:///home/username/Bilder
file:///home/username/Videos
file:///home/username/Downloads
```

After the user directory had been rsync'ed from an external drive into the new installation, that file had the old username. Once those five lines were updated, it was all normal again.